# How to render a modal after failed update in Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I use a modal window to edit a schedule from the schedules index. Each schedule provides a **link** to the edit method:

```
<%= link_to edit_scheduler_production_schedule_path(schedule), 
            title: t('.Edit'), 
            data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#childModal" }, 
            class: "mat-icon-button mat-button-base mat-secondary" do %>
  <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
<% end %>
```

The **edit method** from ProductionSchedulesController is quite simple:

```
  # GET /production_schedules/1/edit
  def edit

    render layout: false
  end
```

So is the **edit.html.erb** file:

```
<% provide :childModalTitle do %>
  <%= t('.Edit') %>
<% end %>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

And the **edit form** is quite light too:

```
<%= form_with model: [namespace, @production_job, @production_schedule], html: {id: "edit_form"} do |f| %>

  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="editScheduleModalLabel">
      <%= t('scheduler.production_schedules.edit.Edit') %>
    </h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= render partial: "shared/error_list", locals: { errors: @production_schedule.errors } %>

    <section class="tabbable" id="schedule_information">
    ---
    </section>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="mat-stroked-button mat-button-base" data-dismiss="modal">
      <%= t('Cancel') %>
    </button>
    <button class="mat-flat-button mat-button-base mat-primary">
      <%= t('Submit') %>
    </button>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

The **update method** is the place where I get frustrated:

```
  # PATCH/PUT /production_schedules/1 or /production_schedules/1.json
  def update
    @production_job = ProductionJob.find(@production_schedule.production_job_id)
    Rails.logger.interactions.info "Schedule update - id: #{@production_schedule.id},
                                    code: #{@production_schedule.code},
                                    mode: #{@production_schedule.mode.code}"
    if @production_schedule.mode.code == 'TEST' or @production_schedule.mode.code == 'MESSAGE'
      @production_schedule.next_run = nil
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @production_schedule.update(production_schedule_params)
        json_parameters_serialization(@production_schedule)
        @production_schedule.update_attribute(:status_id, statuses.find { |x| x["code"] == "READY" }.id || 0)
        format.html { redirect_to scheduler_production_job_path(@production_job), notice: "Production schedule was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @production_schedule }
      else
        @production_schedule.update_attribute(:status_id, statuses.find { |x| x["code"] == "INACTIVE" }.id || 0)
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @production_schedule.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

If the update fails, edit view is rendered, **but not in a modal**.

**How can I re-render this form in a modal** when the update method rejects the update?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since you are using `form_with` without `local: true`, it should send request in JS format, instead of HTML format. Can you confirm this ?

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 6.0 and 5.2, all forms using `form_with` implement `remote: true` by default. These forms will submit data using an XHR (Ajax) request. So, you need to respond to the request in the same format.

Update modal body of **edit_form** (Wrapping error messages in div)

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div id="errorList">
    <%= render partial: "shared/error_list", locals: { errors: @production_schedule.errors } %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add **update.js.erb**

```rb
    <% if (!@production_schedule.errors.present?) %>
      window.location.reload(); # To refresh the page.
    <% else %> # To render error messages in modal when update failed.
      $("#errorList").html('<%= escape_javascript( render(partial: "shared/error_list", locals: { errors: @production_schedule.errors) ) %>');
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Rahul. I understand the process, but after analysing the response, I see that it comes back as HTML and executes: format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }. So the update.js is never executed.